# returned objects within a list while keeping the original data structure in R

Tags: r, list, function

In R, I need to return two objects from a function:

```
myfunction()
{
 a.data.frame <- read.csv(file = input.file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".")
 index.hash <- get_indices_function(colnames(a.data.frame))

 alist <- list("a.data.frame" = a.data.frame, "index.hash" = index.hash)

 return(alist)
}
```

But, the returned objects from myfunction all become list not data.frame and hash.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only return one object from an R function; this is consistent with..pretty much every other language I've used. However, you'll note that the objects retain their original structure *within* the list - so alist[[1]] and alist[[2]] should be the data frame and hash respectively, and are structured *as* data frames and hashes. Once you've returned them from the function, you can split them out into unique objects if you want :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `structure`.

```
return (structure(class = "myclass",
                   list(data = daza.frame,
                        type = anytype,
                        page.content = page.content.as.string.vector,
                        knitr = knitr)))
```

Than you can access your data with

```
values <- my function(...)
values$data
values$type
values$page.content
values$knitr
```

and so on.

A working example from my package:

```
sju.table.values <- function(tab, digits=2) {
  if (class(tab)!="ftable") tab <- ftable(tab)
  tab.cell <- round(100*prop.table(tab),digits)
  tab.row <- round(100*prop.table(tab,1),digits)
  tab.col <- round(100*prop.table(tab,2),digits)
  tab.expected <- as.table(round(as.array(margin.table(tab,1)) %*% t(as.array(margin.table(tab,2))) / margin.table(tab)))
  # -------------------------------------
  # return results
  # -------------------------------------
  invisible (structure(class = "sjutablevalues",
                       list(cell = tab.cell,
                            row = tab.row,
                            col = tab.col,
                            expected = tab.expected)))
}

tab <- table(sample(1:2, 30, TRUE), sample(1:3, 30, TRUE))
# show expected values
sju.table.values(tab)$expected
# show cell percentages
sju.table.values(tab)$cell
```

Comment: I'm utterly confused as to what you are doing. Why are you using `structure`? It doesn't seem to give any advantage over just returning a `list`. All your examples would work just as well.

Comment: You're right, both approaches seem feasible. However, to me it's also a matter of "coding style" and using a structure gives the advantage of assigning attributes (see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html), which is, in my experience, often used in package functions when values are returned.

Comment: It has the disadvantage of being far more obfuscated, however. Lists are pretty much standard for this task for a reason.